# Gradle Multi-Module Build with custom source sets: Missing Classes in Compile Classpath of dependent modules

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, multi-module, source-sets

I'm currently contributing to the OpenLineage Spark integration, a project entirely in Java and built with Gradle (8.4). It's a multi-module project with modules named `app`, `shared`, `spark2`, `spark3`, `spark32`, `spark33`, `spark34`, and `spark35`.

**Problem:**
I am attempting to build the `shared` module for both Scala 2.12 and 2.13 variants of Apache Spark. All the modules (`spark2` to `spark35`) depend on `shared`. My goal is to compile modules like `spark35` to produce two builds: one for Scala 2.12 and another for Scala 2.13 variants of Apache Spark. This also requires the `shared` module to be correctly built with the corresponding Spark variant to avoid runtime errors.

**Approach Taken:**
I've introduced source sets `scala213` and `testScala213` inside `spark33`, `spark34`, `spark35`, and `shared`, using the Java library plugin. These source sets consumed the same sources as the `main` and `test` source  Dependencies are set default for Scala 2.12 variants of Apache Spark, and I have additional declarations for the Scala 2.13 source set. This includes a dependency on the `shared` module.

**Issue Encountered:**
When I request the `scala213RuntimeElements` (or even the `scala213ApiElements` configuration) from the `shared` project, the compile classpath does not include the compiled classes from the `shared` module. However, reverting to the default configuration, these classes are present in the classpath.

**Question:**
Why does specifying a particular configuration (`scala213RuntimeElements`) cause the compile classes of the `shared` module to be missing from my compile classpath in my other modules? How can I resolve this issue to ensure the `shared` module's classes are included in the classpath for both Scala 2.12 and 2.13 builds?

Below you will find my various `build.gradle` files.

**shared/build.gradle**

```
sourceSets {
    scala213 {
        java.srcDir("src/main/java")
        resources.srcDir("src/main/resources")
    }

    testScala213 {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.scala213.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.scala213.output

        java.srcDir("src/test/java")
        resources.srcDir("src/test/resources")
    }
}

configurations {
    scala213Api
    
    scala213ApiElements {
        extendsFrom(scala213Api)
        canBeResolved = false
        canBeConsumed = true
    }
    
    scala213Implementation.extendsFrom(scala213Api)
    
    scala213RuntimeElements {
        extendsFrom(scala213Implementation, scala213RuntimeOnly)
        canBeResolved = false
        canBeConsumed = true
    }
    
    scala213CompileClasspath {
        extendsFrom(scala213CompileOnly, scala213Implementation)
        canBeResolved = true
    }

    scala213RuntimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(scala213Implementation, scala213RuntimeOnly)
        canBeResolved = true
    }
    
    testScala213Implementation.extendsFrom(scala213Implementation)
    testScala213RuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(scala213RuntimeOnly)

    testScala213CompileClasspath {
        extendsFrom(testScala213CompileOnly, testScala213Implementation)
        canBeResolved = true
    }

    testScala213RuntimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(testScala213Implementation, testScala213RuntimeOnly)
        canBeResolved = true
    }
}
```

**spark33/build.gradle:**

```
sourceSets {
    scala213 {
        java.srcDir("src/main/java")
        resources.srcDir("src/main/resources")
    }

    testScala213 {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.scala213.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.scala213.output

        java.srcDir("src/test/java")
        resources.srcDir("src/test/resources")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(path: ":shared"))
    // others removed for brevity

    scala213Implementation(project(path: ":shared", configuration: "scala213RuntimeElements"))
    // others removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out. It's a case of RTFM.

Specifically, [this part of the manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:simple-sharing-artifacts-between-projects). I was not adding the "variant" artifact to the `shared` project. Ergo, Gradle didn't know what it was suppose to consume. Confusingly enough, the default configurations uses the classes, whereas variants require JARs.